# How to select specific form and class and ID together

Tags: jquery, forms, class

How can I select the element with id "list" in my code?

```
<center>
  <form id="form1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control text-center border-primary" id=list rows="3"></textarea>
      <button type="button" id="button" onclick="send();" class="btn btn-dark">Start</button><br>
    </div>
  </form>
</center>
```

I'm trying to select the element with id "list" using jQuery...

```
var line = $('#form1 .form-group #list').val();
```

But I get the following error:

> "TypeError: line is undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you want to select the value of the textarea. Your id, first of all isn't quoted.
Second, you made a spelling error in your id.

So either change this line

`<textarea class="form-control text-center border-primary" id=lista rows="3"></textarea>`

to

`<textarea class="form-control text-center border-primary" id="list" rows="3"></textarea>`

Other than that it is not needed to cascade your search like that if you use an ID. Simply:
`$(#list).val()` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

you can chain you select statements if you want

```
var $list = $('#form1').find('.form-group').find('#list');
```

But this is kind of unnecessary if you have the id of the list, since all ids in the html are supposed to be unique.

So you can directly do `$('#list')`

Comment: `$('#form1').find('.form-group').find('#list')` is exactly equivalent to the `$('#form1 .form-group #list')` they're already using, so there's not much point suggesting that.   You're right that `$('#list')` is better, though.